# How can I compare 2 Lists<String> and return the difference as a list also?

Tags: dart

I'm a beginner in Dart. I have 2 lists.

```
List<String> a = ['John','Ella','Kattie'];
List<String> b = ['Ella'];
```

Is there any method to be called that returns me a

```
List<String> c = ['John','Kattie'];
```

?

I checked the docs but I couldn't find something, maybe I was not paying too much attention.
I was trying to hard code this

```
 for(String i in a)
    {
      for(String j in b) {
         if(i != j) {
            c.add(i);
         }
       }
    }
```

But I'm sure there's another way to do that!

Can you help me please? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind using `Set`(I think you wouldn't for this specific case), there is built-in method from `Set` class called `difference` that exactly gives difference of two sets.

```
final a = <String>{'John','Ella','Kattie'};
final b = <String>{'Ella'};

main(){
  print(a.difference(b));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure there is:

```
var solution = a.where((x) => !b.contains(x));
```

Comment: This is more concise but functionally identical to the code OP already has.

Comment: the thing is this is a `O(n^2)` way of doing this. She solution with `Sets` (by @Esen Mehmet) is more efficient since it's `O(n log n)`

Comment: OP asked if there was a method he could call @Didier Prophete, not What is the most efficeint way to compare" Where() is the  closest I could think of.

Answer (score 0):

This is known as a difference function. You can do it the way you are already doing, but it's obviously not ideal since you have to loop over every element in `b` for every element in `a`, giving it a complexity of `O(m * n)`. There's also the `where(contains)` approach which is far more compact, but ultimately does the same thing.

The most performant way to do it is to convert the second list into a set and compare it that way:

```dart
final bSet = Set.from(b);
final c = [];
for (var x in a) {
  if (!bSet.contains(x)) {
    c.add(x);
  }
}
```

Now that the second list is a set, `contains` lookups are constant time, so the only complex step is the conversion to a step. Now that you are looping over both lists only one time each, giving a complexity of `O(m + n)`.